# WCF hosted in IIS, Problem connecting to database with integrated security

Tags: iis, database-connection, wcf-binding, integrated-security, trustedconnection

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS 5.1 on my development XP machine. The service cannot connect to sql server DB with integrated security=true. The same service works fine when hosted in a console app. I have unchecked Anonymous access and checked the Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS

These are my setting in Web.Config

```
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="CADISEntities"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/UDI.CADISEntities.csdl|res://*/UDI.CADISEntities.ssdl|res://*/UDI.CADISEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=DBSQLP404;Initial Catalog=CadisCustom;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

I have tried changing to Integrated security to SSPI and Trusted Connection =Yes, but no luck. Below is the Config settings.

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CADISBehaviour" name="GlobalInvestors.FIPA.BLL.UDI.CADISSecurities">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CADISBinding"
      contract="GlobalInvestors.FIPA.BLL.UDI.ICADISSecurities" />
  </service>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CADISBinding" closeTimeout="01:30:00" openTimeout="01:30:00"
      receiveTimeout="01:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00" maxBufferSize="65536000"
      maxBufferPoolSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" />
      </security>
    </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
```

and in client

```
  <endpoint address="http://ainaost4.amerus.corp.tld/FIPA/BLLHost/CADIS.svc"
    behaviorConfiguration="Behavior" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICADISSecurities" contract="CADISEntities.ICADISSecurities"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_ICADISSecurities">
    <!--<identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="AINAOST4\ASPNET" />
    </identity>-->
  </endpoint>

    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICADISSecurities" closeTimeout="01:30:00"
      openTimeout="01:30:00" receiveTimeout="01:30:00" sendTimeout="01:30:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="655360000" maxBufferPoolSize="655360000" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360000"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

Without setting Impersonation in the code I get "**The underlying provider failed on Open**"  setting Impersonation in the code and I get "**Cannot Initialize SSPI**"

```
 [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
```

Tried googling and found that Application pool cannot be set in IIS 5.1.

Any suggestion to fix the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: fixed the issue by giving fully qualified sql server name in the connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed the issue by giving fully qualified sql server name in the connection string